# How to end a service in Spring boot and @GetMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed a service REST with Spring Boot, however when I have generated the .jar and excecute it, I do not know how to finished it. (I do not like using Ctrl + Alt + Supr).

Does anyone know how to exit an application (of Spring Boot / REST service), for example:

```
@GetMapping()
public void endApplication(){
 .....End Application .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the point of a service is to run indefinitely.

However, in your example, you could implement it this way:

```
@GetMapping()
public void endApplication(){
    System.exit(0);
}
```